# how to update the delete data in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

so i have this function that update my task manager with new data every 2 second, it work but i am kinda confused to make condition to separate the update data where the data is delete and the data that have been add, can anyone help me? as for now this is my code. as you can see if the data[i] is undefined it will keep getting the first condition of nested if that is deleting the div base of it id what i want to do is that only add the delete codition to the template if the data is delete from the database and same thing goes for new data that being add to the database

```
function update_task_manager(){
    var id_task_pertama = []
    $(".admin-task").each(function(){
        id_task_pertama.push(this.value);
    })
    console.log(id_task_pertama)
    $.ajax({
        method:"GET",
        url:"taskadmin",
        success:function(response){
            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            if(data.length == "0"){
                $("#task-manager").empty();
            }
            else{
                for (var i=0; i < id_task_pertama.length; i++){ 
                        if(typeof(data[i]) == "undefined"){
                            if(data.includes(id_task_pertama[i])){
                                var link = $('.admin-task[value="' + id_task_pertama[i] + '"]');
                                var parent = link.parent();
                                parent.remove();
                            }else{
                                add_data = 
                                '<li class="admin-task" value='+data[i].id+'>'+
                                    '<div class="admin-image">'+
                                        '<img src="{%static "image/dedek.jpg" %}" alt="image-admin">'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="task-admin">'+
                                        '<div class="admin-name-due">'+
                                            '<label>'+data[i].username+'</label>'+
                                            '<small>Due:'+data[i].task_tenggat+'</small>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                        '<div class="task-subject-task">'+
                                            '<label>'+data[i].subject+'</label>'+
                                            '<div class="button-task">'+
                                            '   <div clas="detail-task">'+
                                                    '<button id="tampilkan-detail-task" value='+data[i].id+'>Detail Task<i class="fa fa-file" style="margin-left:5px"aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '   <div class="button-status">'+
                                                    '<button><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'+
                                                    '<button><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</li>'
                                $('#task-manager').append(add_data);
                                console.log("berhasil append");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    update_task_manager();
},2000)
```

the data it send

[image]

Comment: rewrite your question to be more readable and understandable

Comment: sorry if you confused of my question, i have rewrite my question and sorry for my bad English, English is not my first language :)

Comment: still dont get what you want your code to acheive. I can only help if i see a bit more code.

Comment: so which part you do get it sir?

Comment: so your code is making updates to a div and dynamically adding to this div? is this correct

Comment: yep and i rewrite my code i meant in question

Comment: can you make your update function only update and remove the delete part.

Comment: you meant to separate the function to update and remove ?

Comment: yes that is what i mean

Comment: i don't think it can because the way my code work is that it  check the data id(from the response) if the data id is in id_task_pertama it will not append but if the data is undefined or the data not in the id_task_pertama it append(i do this so it wont append the same data every request) <== this part is the problem don't know what condition should i make to separate the delete one and the add one

Comment: create a function that checks if the `id_task_pertama`  contains the data about to be added

Comment: this function will return true or false

Comment: very important lesson in coding always separate your concerns. jamming them together will only get you confused

Comment: alright..i try to make it

Comment: i did it, thanks dude

Comment: sure dude ill update it